# Remove orphan-language-icon from menu bar

Tags: input-language

I am using 16.04, somehow I manage to leave an orphan-language-icon on my menu bar (see high-lighted item in menu bar).  I could't remove it in system settings/language support.  Does anyone know if this item can be removed by editing a config file?  Or can be changed from command line?
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdseC.png)

And by entering gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources, I got [('ibus', 'bopomofo'), ('xkb', 'us'), ('ibus', 'libbopomofo')].  First one seems to be the orphan.

Comment: Try _System Settings -> Text Entry_

Comment: Unfortunately there's no corresponding entry there either.

Comment: Uncheck "Show current input source in the menu bar".

Comment: Well, I still want to keep the other two.  I just want to remove the orphan one.

Comment: Aha, finally I understand what you are asking about. :) It may be an orphan `gsettings` value. Can you please run the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` and let us know what it outputs by editing your question.

Comment: Ah, thank you for your patience and input.  So I typed in the command you mentioned and find out which one is the orphan, and then do a 'set' to remove the orphan, now I am happy to report that orphan input method no longer appears!  Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Good. It would be great if you could post that solution as an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

So with Gunnar's suggestion, I realize I can use following command to reset keyboard input setting.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us'), ('ibus', 'libbopomofo')]"
```

where string (within double-quote) are the input methods I want to keep.

Again, thanks Gunnar.